# How come "Move To" does not move all files?

Tags: sharepoint-online, move

Using SharePoint Online, whenever I attempt to move a folder, via the "Move To" menu option, it seems to only move some of the files.  It looks like all folders are created in the destination location, but only some of the files are moved.  There's no rhyme or reason to why some files are moved while others are not.

The progress screen appears to show all of them having moved, but checking the destination location does not show them as being there and they still remain in the source location.

Answer (score 0):

I tested in my end with several different files and they are all properly moved. Do you have enough permission on all these files? To Move, you will need at least “Add” permissions in the target site AND “Delete” permissions in the source site, as Move deletes the documents in the source site.

Does the same issue occur on the whole tenant or on certain files?

The move to function simply is not intended for moving large number of files, as you did not receive any notifications about file move failure, it may be better for you to get a service request.